# Java explicit casting on list.get(0) (incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, casting

The following code is mentioned in the Java Tutorials :-(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello");
String s = (String) list.get(0);
```

The casting in the last line suggests that list.get(0) does not return a String. Now, since list was not declared with any data type, it can take in any object. So I assumed that list.get(0) returns an Object type.

But when I check   `list.get(0) instanceof String`  --> it returns true.

Why is then the explicit casting required. Please explain.

Comment: What happened when you will add `list.add(1000L);`, it will compile without any issue but will be failed at run time in casting to String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I assumed that list.get(0) returns an Object type.

Yes it does.

> But when I check list.get(0) instanceof String --> it returns true.

Yes, it should return **true** because the item at index `0` of the `list` **is a `String`**.

> Why is then the explicit casting required.

it's required simply because the list contains `Object`s and not every `Object` from the list is guaranteed to be a `String`.  The explicit cast is required so that you can assign the reference of `list.get(0)` to `s` (a variable of type `String`).

Comment: This answer covers the various parts of OP's question, but one small addition: generics can make this a little simpler. The list can be defined to contain `String`, like this: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. Then a `get()` will not require a cast, so you can do this: `String s = list.get(0);`

Comment: thanks. fwiw in general I make no assumptions about what OP does or doesn't know. :)

Comment: @kaan Alright I see. fair enough and a good reason too tbh. I shouldn't have assumed... :).

Comment: thank you guys! really appreciate the way you explain :)

Answer (score 2):

> The casting in the last line suggests that list.get(0) does not return a String.

That's inaccurate. If the returned object **wasn't** a `String`, then casting wouldn't have been possible. In other words, you can only cast something to `String` if that something is a `String`. Try casting something else, you'll see:

```
Object i = Integer.valueOf(5);
String j = (String)i; //Exception!
```

The cast is needed in your code because `list.get(0)` returns an `Object` type, but we want to assign it to a `String s`. We as the programmers know that the `Object` returned from the list is in fact a `String`, but the compiler doesn't. The compiler just sees this:

```
Object l = list.get(0);
String s = l;
```

The second line cannot compile without an explicit cast to `String`.

And just for clarification.. you'll never see such code in the real world unless you're working on something seriously old. Java has generics since Java 5 (2004), so 15 years now. At this point you really shouldn't see `List` without it being `List<SomeType>` (e.g. `List<String>`)

Answer (score 1):

The `List list = new ArrayList();` is an unparameterized type (which you want to avoid), meaning it can take any `Object`.

Since your `list` contains any `Object`s, `list.get(0);` can only know that it's returning an `Object` and doesn't know that the element at 0 is actually a `String`. Since it doesn't *know* that it's really a `String` the compiler warns you that you're doing an unchecked cast from `Object` to `String`.

`list.get(0) instanceof String` returns true because it's a runtime check that the element at 0 is in fact a `String`.